# Find the people who are in most courses

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to find the people who are enrolled in most courses. My result should be :

```
    Name     EnrolledCount
    David       4
    Mary        4
```

So far I have come up with the following query :

```
SELECT  S.Name,COUNT(*) AS EnrolledCount
FROM Student S
JOIN Student E ON S.id = E.id
GROUP BY S.Name
```

The result I am getting from the above query is :

```
  Name  EnrolledCount
  David     4
  Jane      1
  John      2
  Mary      4
  Tom       2
```

Any pointers/suggestions please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want just the ones Enrolled the maximum number try using a Common Table Expression like this (there are other solutions.)

```
;with Enrolled (name, EnrolledCount) 
as 
(SELECT S.Name, COUNT(*) AS EnrolledCount 
FROM Student S
GROUP BY S.Name
)   
Select * from Enrolled 
where EnrolledCount = (select max(enrolledCount) from enrolled)
order by name  desc
```

Answer (score 1):

Second Edit - using the Ranking function over the count of records in descending order:

```
SELECT final.ID, final.Name, final.EnrollmentCount
  FROM (SELECT r.ID, 
               r.Name, 
               r.EnrollmentCount, 
               Ranking = RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY r.ID ORDER BY r.EnrollmentCount DESC)
          FROM (SELECT s.ID, 
                       s.Name, 
                       EnrollmentCount = COUNT(*)
                  FROM Student s
                 GROUP BY s.ID, s.Name) r) final
  WHERE final.Ranking = 1
```

What the above accomplishes is first identifies the Enrollment Counts (innermost query) followed by the ranking over those counts (inner query) returning the results filtering for a ranking of 1.

---

```
SELECT S.Name, S.EnrolledCount
  FROM Student S
 WHERE S.EnrolledCount = (SELECT MAX(i.EnrolledCount) FROM Student i)
```

Edit - I see now that your Student table doesn't actually have the EnrolledCount on it, rather, it contains all Student enrollments and thus the NUMBER of times the Student shows up is the count for that student.

```
SELECT S.ID, S.Name, EnrolledCount = COUNT(*)
  FROM Student S
 GROUP BY S.ID, S.Name
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT TOP 1 COUNT(*) 
                     FROM Student i 
                    GROUP BY i.ID 
                    ORDER BY 1 DESC)
```

Comment: Enrolledcount is not a field it is an alias.

Comment: This query is not yeilding the expected result.

Comment: @Forty3 You can actually move your `RANK()` into the `r` query and eliminate the need for the doubly nested query.  It would look like `SELECT s.ID, s.Name, EnrollmentCount = COUNT(*), Ranking = RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) FROM...`

Comment: Excellent. I didn't think the Rank would like the Count in the Order By. Thanks.